# VBscript for filename renaming with datestamp

Tags: datetime, date, vbscript, batch-file

I need to get all the files in a folder be get appended with today's date and time stamp in the following format : filename_mmddyyyy.fileextension. Could someone please please help on this or can this be done using a bat script.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code, as bad or as little as it is, it really helps, the FormatDateTime takes your locals in account, i'm in Flanders, Europe so my system adds _19062012.ext but on your system it should be _06192012.ext

```
set oFso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
sDirectorypath = "c:\testing"
rename_files(sDirectorypath)

sub rename_files(folder)
  set oFolder = oFso.getfolder(folder)
  for each oFile in oFolder.files
    new_name = oFile & "_" & replace(FormatDateTime(now,2),"/","") & "." & oFso.GetExtensionName(oFile)
    wscript.echo "renaming " & oFile & " => " & new_name
    errResult = oFso.MoveFile(oFile, new_name)
  next
  for each oSubFolder in oFolder.subfolders
    rename_files(oSubFolder)
  next
end sub
```

Comment: While the () in the Sub call, using a string instead of a folder object as parameter, and not testing for existence of a file with new_name, are matters of style and taste, using of .MoveFile as a function (errResult) isn't valid VBScript.

Comment: when it runs without problems it's valid in my book Ekkehard, i test all my answers if possible and as i said multiple times before, come up with your own solutions in stead of picking on those who take time and interest to answer

Comment: on the issue of checking if exist, if this script is not run with a scheduler it SHOULD fail if a file allready exists with that name

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done in a batch file :-)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "timestamp="
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do (
  if not defined timestamp set "timestamp=%%A"
)
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d myFolder\*') do (
  if "%%~fF" neq "%~f0" ren "%%F" "%%~nF_%timestamp:~4,4%%timestamp:~0,4%%%~xF
)
```

Care must be taken to make sure the batch file does not rename itself - it will fail if it is renamed while running.